# How to fix IDE complaints about IDE0059 without restarting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, static-code-analysis

My Visual Studio complains about an unnecessary assignment of a value to a variable, [IDE0059](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0059).

[image: VS Screenshot of IDE0059]

My code (part of a unit test) is

```cs
var result = parser.Parse(Resource.String1);
Assert.AreEqual("-6:00", result.DailyTimeBalance);
```

and IMHO the variable is clearly used after the assignment.

What could I do to get rid of this false positive without restarting Visual Studio?

I have tried:

- rebuilding the unit test project - does not help
- unloading the unit test project and reloading it - does not help
- restarting Visual Studio - helps

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.10

Comment: Is it valid to try changing `csharp_style_unused_value_assignment_preference` to `unused_local_variable`?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT: why is the variable unused? I don't want to replace the warning by a different warning.